# How do I add elements to a dynamic array and exclude exsisting elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

```
function addNumifnotThere(numer){
   var numCent = [];

     numCent.forEach(function(){
        if(numer in numCent)
         console.log("you logged that");
        else
         numCent.push(numer);


 });
return numCent;
}
```

This is my current code, what its attempting to do is read an array and if there is already an element exits the loop and says "you already logged that", obviously if it cannot find a similar element then it pushes it to the array.

I want this to work dynamically so we cannot know the size of the array beforehand, so the first element passed as an argument should be put into the array, (addNum(1) should have the array print out [1], calling addNum(1) again should print "you already logged that")

However there are two problems with this
1) Trying to push to a new array without any entries means everything is undefined and therefore trying to traverse the array just causes the program to print [].

2) Adding some random elements to the array just to make it work, in this case numCent=[1,2,3] has other issues, mainly that adding a number above 3 causes the code to print incorrect information. In this case addNum(5) should print [1,2,3,5] but instead prints [1,2,3,5,5,5]

I know this has to be a simple mistake but I've been dragging myself too long to not ask for help.

EDIT: Thanks to the many outstanding answers here I have now leanred about the indexOf method, thank you guys so much.

Comment: I'm confused; you want to keep the contents of an array, but you're creating a new array on the first line of the function?

Comment: why don't you use a lodash.js library and use it "includes" `https://lodash.com/docs#includes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do do this cleanly, I'd consider prototyping the global `Array` object and adding a method to push values but only if they're unique to the array. Something like this:

```
Array.prototype.pushUnique = function (item) {
    if (this.indexOf(item) != -1) {
        console.log("Item with value of " + item + " already exists in the array."
    }
    else {
        this.push(item);
    }
}
```

If you're not comfortable prototypeing global types like `Array`, you can build the same thing in a procedural pattern:

```
function arrayPushUnique (arr, item) {
    if (arr.indexOf(item) != -1) {
        console.log("Item with value of " + item + " already exists in the array."
    }
    else {
        arr.push(item);
    }
}
```

Then to use it, simply create a new empty array and start pushing things to it.

```
var numCent = [];
// The Array.prototype method
numCent.pushUnique(number);
// The procedural method
arrayPushUnique(numCent, number);
```

Answer (score 0):

For every non-match you are pushing the number. Use something like this

```
var numCent = [];
function addNumifnotThere(numer)
{
    var index = numCent.indexOf(number);
    if(index >=0)
    {
       console.log("you logged that");
    }
    else
    {
       numCent.push(number);
    }

    return numCent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.indexOf`

```js
var numCent = [];
function addNum(numer){

        if (numCent.indexOf(numer) > -1)
        {
            console.log("Number already in array");    
        }
        else
        {
           numCent.push(numer);
        }
} 

//DEMO CODE, not part of solution
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (document.querySelector("input").value.length > 0)
  {
      addNum(document.querySelector("input").value);
      document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = numCent.join(", ");
  }
}, false);
```

```html
Output
<div id="output"></div>

<input />
<button>Add number</button>
```

`indexOf` tests if an element is inside the array and returns its index. If not found it will return `-1`. You can test for this. You can try it for your self in this snippet. It will only allow you to add a number (or any string, in this example) once.

> I also was confused by the newCent array declaration inside the function. I think, based upon the content of your question, you meant this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the array held in the instance, you can do it like this.

```
function AddIf(arr){
  if( arr || !this.arr ) {
    this.arr = arr || [];
  }

  return function(number) {
    if( this.arr.indexOf(number) >= 0 ) {
      console.log("Already Present!");
    } else {
      this.arr.push(number);
    }

    return this.arr;
  }.bind(this);
}

// Usage would be like this:
// var addIf = new AddIf([1, 2, 3]);
// addIf(10);  // returns [1, 2, 3, 10]
// addIf(10);  // logs "Already Present!", doesn't add 10 to array
```

This basically returns a function, with `this` bound to the function being called.  If you pass in an initial array, it will use that array to compare to when adding it to the array.

You can catch the return function and call it as you would want to.  If you don't call `new` when invoking however, it will share the same array instance (and have a funky way of being called, `AddIf()(10)`).

I used `fn.bind()` to ensure the function gets called in the correct context every time, if you were wondering why I called it like that.